# Generate JSONPath based on condition

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

Json

```
{
    "Id": "1234",
    "AValue": {
        "qId": "ABCD",
        "aType": "DATE",
        "value": {
            "eType": "ENCRYPTED",
            "eValue": "XXXXXXX"
        }
    }

}
```

How to write a jsonpath expression to get **eValue** only if "qId in AValue is ABCD"

Comment: what have you tried until now? Check some example here https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$.store.bicycle[?(@.color==%22red%22)].price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use conditions

```
$.AValue[?(@.qId =="ABCD")].value.eValue
```